# How to add undulation to a constraint-based chain?

Tags: physics, movement, godot, rope-physics

I have a constraint-based chain composed of segments where each of the terminal segments has a fixed position.

[image]

My constraints are set up as follows:

```
var segments = [segment0, segment1, segment2, segment3, segment4, segment5, segment6]

# terminal segments follow head and anchor
segments[0].global_position = head.global_position
segments[segments.size() - 1].global_position = anchor.global_position

for x in range(4): # iterate 4 times

    for i in segments.size() - 1:
        var desired_distance = 8

        var current_segment = segments[i]
        var prev_segment_position = current_segment.global_position if i == 0 or i == segments.size() - 1 else segments[i - 1].global_position
        var next_segment_position = current_segment.global_position if i == 0 or i == segments.size() - 1 else segments[i + 1].global_position

        # get vector from previous to next and find midpoint
        var prev_to_next = next_segment_position - prev_segment_position
        var midpoint = prev_segment_position + prev_to_next.normalized() * prev_to_next.length() * 1/2

        # move current segment to midpoint
        var vec_to_midpoint = midpoint - current_segment.global_position
        current_segment.global_position += vec_to_midpoint
```

My question is: **How can I implement random undulation in this chain?**

In other words, I want the intermediate segments to move smoothly in a random wave pattern, while the terminal segments remain fixed to their positions.

[image]

Ideally, I'd set it up with some parameters than I could adjust to control the speed and volatility of the undulation.

I am working in Godot 3.1, but would like an engine-neutral explanation of the technique.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this function, it produces waves and maintains edges at zero:

[image]

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/aloi3ydowg

I guess you can position your elements by evaluating it accordingly.